# How to rotate tomcat logs in Windows? What is the best method?

Tags: windows, tomcat, rotation, logging

I am really fed up in not being able to solve the tomcat log rotation problem in one our windows server after putting countless hours in it and after trying out various solutions.

- **Environment:** Java 1.6x, Tomcat 6 (running as service), log4j 1.2, Server 2003 32-bit

Methods tried so far:

1. `cronolog` didn't work, no files where being created after setting it up.
2. Managed to configure `log4j` with `DailyRollingFile` appender globally for Tomcat, the log files are being created without extension and are not being rotated.
3. Tried `DatedFileAppender` too, but didn't get much success.
4. Tried `log4jna` based `Windows Event Log appender` for log4j, there didn't get success

Please suggest an easy method to finish this task.

Comment: FYI: OP answered this himself. [See below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079915/how-to-rotate-tomcat-logs-in-windows-what-is-the-best-method/15676581#15676581). -- @Raghu: Please consider placing the green "accepted answer" checkmark on your own answer to signify that it worked for you.

Answer (score 4):

Apache Tomcat provides the configuration directory **conf**, that contains the file **server.xml**. At the bottom of
this file, a line that includes the adjustments valve, called
**AccessLogValve** must be un-commented and changed.

The default valve parameters and patterns can easily be
modified through an editor. Your settings for the access log file for example may look like this:

```
<Valve
className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve."
directory="logs"
prefix="mysite."
suffix=".log"
pattern='%a %A %b %B %h %l %m %p %q %u %t "%r" %s %U %D %S'
resolveHosts="false"
rotatable="true"
fileDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
/>
```

This sentence is from the [Tomcat reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/valve.html):

> The *fileDateFormat* parameter allows a customized date format in the
>   access log file name. The date format also decides how often the file
>   is rotated. If you wish to rotate every hour, then set this value to:
>   *yyyy-MM-dd.HH*

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to write to me such detailed reply.

You are approaching the problem from totally a different angle.
I am not sure whether this would solve my problem or not.
But as of now i have managed to configure the logs rotation via dailyrollingfile appender in log4j

Comment: Still logs are not being rotated even after successfully configuring the dailyrollingfile appender.

I think log4j can't rename a file when being used by Tomcat in Windows.

Please suggest me other options

Answer (score 2):

I have finally resolved the problem after a long stretch. This time, i have not touched tomcat log configuration. I used a fantastic utility called logrotatewin which is an reimplementation of logrotate in Windows. I was already familiar with logrotate, so setting up logrotatewin was an easy job. I had to stop tomcat in prerun and start it back in postrun for the log rotation to work, as tomcat locks the log file when it is running.

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching on how to rotate the Access Valve logs. From what ever data I have gathered so far, the 'rotation' would simply switch over to the next file based on the fileDateFormat value that you set.

For e.g. a value of "yyyy-MM-dd.HH" would create a new file every hour. But it seems the files would continue growing in number unless you use an external mechanism like a cron job (in linux) to clean them up.